# Populate Excel Userform Listbox with sheet name, but only for a certain color

Tags: excel, vba, colors, listbox, userform

I am trying to populate a list box with the sheet names. However, I want to pull only the sheets that have a tab of a certain tab color. How can I augment the following VBA code?

```
For n = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    PDFListBox.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n).Name
Next n
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```vb
Dim ws
For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    'only add if tab is (eg) red
    If ws.Tab.color = vbRed Then PDFListBox.AddItem ws.Name
Next n
```